# Google Visualization - sending 2D array , but not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-visualization

for drawing a graph using google visualization, if I send data hardcoded in JS file like this, if works perfectly fine.

```
data.addRows([[100, 30],[200, 70],[246, 150],[512, 780]]);
```

which I understand is clearly is 2D JS array.
But, when I am trying to send it dynamically, it doesn't work. Please check the code for this.

```
dataFromText = "100,30,200,70,246,150,512,780";
dataFromText = dataFromText.split(',');
while(dataFromText[0]) {
        result.push(dataFromText.splice(0,2));
    }
alert(result[1]); // this line  prints 200,70
data.addRows([result]);
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:
As in the code shared by you **result** variable is containing strings instead of number.

```
dataFromText = "100,30,200,70,246,150,512,780";
dataFromText = dataFromText.split(',').map(Number);//converting string to number
var result = [];
while(dataFromText[0]) {
        result.push(dataFromText.splice(0,2));
    }
console.log(result);
data.addRows(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` is already a 2d array, the extra brackets break it. Try removing the square brackets around `result`

```js
var dataFromText = "100,30,200,70,246,150,512,780";
var dataFromText = dataFromText.split(',');
var result=[];
while(dataFromText[0]) {
        result.push(dataFromText.splice(0,2));
    }
console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // this line  prints 2d array
data.addRows(result);
```